# Using struct as wrapper for member function

Tags: c++, templates, struct, function-pointers, template-specialization

I am trying to use a struct as a wrapper for a member function of a class. I have a templated struct that is supposed to hold a pointer to the member function, but in a generic sense not pointing to the instance's specific function. I already figured out the template specilization, but have not been able to figure out the syntax for the storage of the function.

**More clearly**: I have class `X` that has non-static function `doY()` and `doZ()`. In the class I have made, class `A`, I have an instance of `X` named `ex`. Depending on the situation I want to call one of the functions. I have made a struct called `wrapper`. `Wrapper` should store a reference to `doY()` or `doZ()` in a static variable named `function` by using template specilization. I should then be able to call `ex.wrapper::function` to run either `ex.doY()` or `ex.doZ()`.

This is the current version of my code (showing the specialization for some class B), which leads to a `func is not a member of wrapper` error

.h

```
template <class T>
class A
{
    T timer;
    X ex;
    template<class Type>
    struct create_timer_getter{};

    void doSomething()
    {
        timer = ex.wrapper<T>::func();
    }
};
```

.cpp

```
template <>
struct A<B>::wrapper<B>
{
    // V-- this is where I am having issues --V
    static const X::(func)(int, int, char) = &X::doY
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with using `std::function` instead?

Comment: It still just gives me a `function is not a member of wrapper` error

Comment: You have used `X` and `A` and `doY` and `doZ` in your description, then you go off and write code **where you don't use those names**.  You mix "XYZ" with "ABC" in entirely different categories (X and A are classes, Y and Z are functions?).  Your sample code is a template with a specialization and more templates, none of which seem to correspond clearly to your "more clearly" description; your "more clearly" involves no templates.  I think your problem is simple, but your question is so confusing I am no longer sure if the sky is blue.  And your code has `...` in it.  [MCVE].

Comment: The pointer-to-member declaration syntax is `return_type (class_name::*variable_name)(parameter_types)`. The pointer-to-member dereferencing operators are `.*` and `->*`.

Comment: Still not a **complete** example. When I copy this code into a file and compile it, I get _"error: 'X' does not name a type"_ and _"error: 'B' was not declared in this scope"_ and several other errors, none of which match the error mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you molbdnilo, that syntax compiled correctly.

> The pointer-to-member declaration syntax is return_type (class_name::*variable_name)(parameter_types). The pointer-to-member dereferencing operators are .* and ->*

Since then, I have also found an alternative syntax that also works:

```
typedef return_type (class_name::user_defined_type_name)(parameter_types);
user_defined_type_name variable_name = &namespace(if needed)::class_name::member_function_name;
```